# Read barcode from hardware conneceted to system and display in MVC application

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, barcode, reader

- I am writing the mvc application which will display the barcode data in web page.
- As i explored i saw most of the examples are related to scanning the barcode image or barcode in PDF.
- How to directly scan the data and display it in web page and use the barcode value for further processing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve but hardware barcode scanner usually works like keyboard: plug it, select an input in your web page, scan a barcode then your input will be filled with the barcode value

Comment: ya i agree with you that is keyboard wadged barcode reader but what about USB barcode reader

Comment: I do use an USB barcode reader, it works the same way

Comment: I created a web application having textbox i place the cursor and scan the barcode but data is not showing up in the textbox

Comment: It's not related to your web app, try to play with your driver then

Comment: Thanks .. will check drivers properly:)

Comment: I checked from web application barcode value not displaying.  but its working in desktop application.